# Auto reformat doctest in pycharm

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

Is there a way to reformat the python Doctests in the pycharm? Something similar to Ctrl+Alt+L for the code in the python file? The Ctrl+Alt+L or Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L doesn't reformat the doctests in the python file. I am using 2017.2 version of the pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the doctest out of the doc string, reformat them and paste them back in.